# Android 4.4 http api bugs?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I decided to start testing my app with Android 4.4 and noticed that the Android HTTP connection APIs are much stricter than before? I have never had this issue and I assume it is some type of bug.

I'm connecting to SHOUTcast broadcasts that contain the particular icy header response.

Has anyone seen this issue? How can I get around it?

**URL used for this test:**

```
http://50.117.121.162:80
```

**Logcat of exception:**

> 11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081): java.net.ProtocolException:
>   Unexpected status line: ICY 200 OK 11-01 23:47:57.299:
>   E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.setStatusLine(RawHeaders.java:108)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:308)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:135)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:644)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.vblast.xiialive.media.streamers.ConnectHelper.connectWorker(ConnectHelper.java:176)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   com.vblast.xiialive.media.streamers.ConnectHelper.run(ConnectHelper.java:143)
>   11-01 23:47:57.299: E/ConnectHelper(3081):    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Comment: Notice the `okhttp` there. AFAIK HttpURLConnection implementation has been replaced by Square's OkHTTP in Kitkat.

Comment: Yes, I thought something changed under the hood. This stinks. I really need to figure out a way around it. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Android 4.4 things did change under the hood and the none standard SHOUTcast ICY header response is no longer supported. Just like the Apache HTTPClient library.

What I had to do can be found on this post:
[How to parse a none standard HTTP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759966/how-to-parse-a-none-standard-http-response)

Comment: I also added there solution that solves this with Apache HttpClient. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Jona answer is right, but if you are using AACPlayer(https://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/) to play your SHOUTcast, here is a simpler solution: https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/wiki/HandlingShoutcastStreams

Also, I needed to change my url from "http://example.org" to "icy://example.org"

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a solution based on the [Apache HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html), you can find it as [a gist here](https://gist.github.com/toms972/8842217).

Here is how to use it:

```
IcyGetRequest request = new IcyGetRequest(urlStr);
HttpResponse response = request.get();
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```