# aacdecoder-android accplayer fails stream music on 4.4.+

Tags: android, aac, android-4.4-kitkat, android-holo-everywhere

There is a problem with HoloEverywhere and AACDecoder (com.spoledge.aacdecoder).
When I try click play music from stream I get this:

```
12-13 09:50:33.044  24134-24225/com.example.aapxxx E/AACPlayer﹕ playAsync():
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.dumpHeaders(AACPlayer.java:510)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.processHeaders(AACPlayer.java:497)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.MultiPlayer.processHeaders(MultiPlayer.java:108)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:280)
        at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:248)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I've implemented all 4 files into lib and selected aacdecoder jar as source.
HoloEverywhere is using android v4 19 0 1
I stuck and don't know how to fix it.
I'm using Android Studio. I followed as in tutorial [here](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/source/browse/trunk/player/src/com/spoledge/aacplay/AACPlayerActivity.java)
Please help what to do.
Thanks in advance.
I'm trying to be runnin on **4.4**
Works on lower versions.

I could use notpackaged project with sources instead ready jar of accplayer but I don't know how to manage it. Maybe there is just any small bug in theirs code..

Related problem discussion:
[project page issue](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/issues/detail?id=44)
[Android Live Radio comments (second or third comment)](http://codecanyon.net/item/android-live-radio/3697897/comments)

---

**EDIT: 2014-01-09 - PROBABLY FIX**

**On main project page ACCPLAYER in [issue ticket page](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/issues/detail?id=44#c14) has been uploaded FIX for kit kat.**
Problem is related to changes in kiktat which was also mentioned on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738798/android-4-4-http-api-bugs)

Comment: Would be helpful if you paste more code how you prepare your PlayAsync method.. I had a lot of troubles with aac-streams in the past spoledge lib is a good alternative, but it`s not stable (at least it wasn`t 6months ago)..

Answer (score 2):

One shot in the dark...sometimes the connection to stream fails, if there's no `User-Agent` set. But I'm not sure if your problem is because of your headers.. so please provide more (code)information. just for the record -> this is how you could set heards with android `Mediaplayer`. Check if AACDecoder has something similar too...

```
    //Setting HTTP header for fixing some issues with normal setDataSource Header from Android
    //User-Agent "iTunes" was set to force re-direct to shoutcast streaming url     
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("User-Agent", "iTunes");

    setDataSource(context, uri, headers);

    prepareAsync();
```

(full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225076/android-aac-radio-streaming-doesnt-work-with-mediaplayer-android-4-2-2-sho))

Comment: there is no way use that methods